# How do you prevent multiple touch events on the UINavigationBar?

Tags: ios, swift, uibarbuttonitem

I've got two UIBarButtonItem's on my navigation bar, and here's the code I'm trying to make work:

self.navigationController?.navigationBar.exclusiveTouch = true // does not work...
self.navigationController?.navigationBar.multipleTouchEnabled = false // same...

Any solutions to this issue? As it stands, anyone can press both UIBarButtonItem's at the same time and crash the app. Am I not supposed to be using it like this?

Answer (score 0):

For each of the subviews inside the navigation bar, you will want to set `exclusiveTouch = true`.

So, your code should look like this:

```
for view in navigationController.navigationBar.subviews {
    view.exclusiveTouch = true
}
```

Comment: With: self.navigationController?.navigationBar.multipleTouchEnabled = false in the 'viewDidLoad' method; I'm still able to press both UIBarButtonItem's at the same time...

Comment: @user3276937 I updated my answer with another solution that should solve your problem.

Comment: If you're referring to super.navigationController?.navigationBar.multipleTouchEnabled = false it's still not working...the buttons present a popover view if that helps any...

Comment: navigationItem.leftBarButtonItem appears to not have an exclusiveTouch property...

Comment: @user3276937 Okay now I think I got it. It's always tricky finding solutions without a test project to mess around with.

Comment: This solution is cause errors also, I'm going to continue looking for solutions to it. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Sorry I couldn't be more help.